# What does really stimulate some people to oddly believe in special relativity as a self-contradictory theory?

Tags: special-relativity

There have been too many (pseudo-)paradoxes as to special relativity, introduced by both curious laymen and professional scientists since the advent of the theory, most of which have truly been resolved in the framework of relativity.

I want to know what a mental stimulus, esp. a negative mental attitude, urges some people to attack the special theory of relativity by design some new thought-experiments despite the resolutions to the older ones. Why cannot these resolutions convince them that relativity is not flawed? Is it only because of the Newtonian logic that governs our minds? If so, why this destructive behavior/tendency has not been that widely applied to other anti-Newtonian theories; that is, why there is not any considerable endeavor to show that, e.g., classical electrodynamics or quantum mechanics is a self-contradictory theory? Why is it all about special relativity?

Is it really something wrong with these people, or there is a weird deficiency about special relativity that has not just been revealed so far?!

Comment: seems a better fit for https://psychology.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I do not agree with your logic. Paradoxes can be designed by mere curiosity, without any thought about the validity of SR. If one assumes that SR holds, then what is interesting is how the theory resolves the paradoxes. I do not think this has anything to do with "Newtonian logic" either.

Comment: @thermomagnetic condensed boson *"Paradoxes **can be** designed by mere curiosity"* Maybe you are right, but I am afraid that the history of science says something different!

Comment: @thermomagneticcondensedboson I think you might be using a different definition of "paradox" than the OP. The difference is in whether a "resolved" paradox still counts as a paradox (it looks like you say it is, while the OP says it isn't, labeling it instead a pseudo-paradox). Personally, I'm of the opinion that if everything you _think_ is a paradox is resolved within the theory, then the theory has no paradoxes. Paradoxes are, to me, only unresolvable contradictions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a physics question.

Comment: perhaps because it is easy to both  understand and misunderstand the theory. Quantum theory is so weird there is small chance of understanding it on intuitive level - you simply need to do the math. And math is exact. On the other hand, classical electrodynamics is pretty hard to misunderstand, since all of the theory seems pretty natural to most people. And here you have relativity - the theory that has simple principles with simple math that even high schooler can learn it well on his own, but it is still wierd enaugh for a lot of misunderstanding to happen.

Comment: @Umaxo Relevant xkcd: https://xkcd.com/1861/

Comment: Some people still very actively attack the _globe Earth_ model, finding supposed "paradoxes" that according to them, do not fit within the laws of physics.  It doesn't seem surprising to me that people would also attack a theory that is far less intuitive and harder to grasp.  It's not like questioning theories is necessarily bad either; you just should make sure you understand the actual theory first.

Comment: While not really a physics question, there is an explanation. Human consciousness or more precisely self awareness is the awareness of the existence in time, of the flow of time. As such, conscious creatures like people cannot easily conceive time as anything, but an infinite straight number line. Any theory where time is relative, dilated, starts or stops is counterintuitive and repulsive to the human mind. In the Newtonian physics, time is absolute, the same as in the human mind, and thus is intuitively acceptable. This is not physics, so I am not posting this as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps your question is more suited to the psychology stack exchange, but on the assumption that relatively few psychologists will have thought much about SR, perhaps it is worth making the exception to discuss it here.

My personal experience was that, having been naturally gifted at physics at school, and despite having a PhD in quantum theory, I found relativity extremely difficult to internalise, even though I could follow the mathematical arguments straightforwardly. I think that was because I had in my schooldays deeply programmed my mind to accept the truth of Euclidean geometry- all of my mental conceptions about physics were built upon it, so that my main challenge in understanding SR was actually ridding myself of my ingrained thought patterns.

So, if we drum into the heads of the schoolchildren that the world is Euclidean, we can hardly be surprised if they later struggle to accept the opposite is true for the universe more generally. I suspect a similar principle applies in the case of religion, in which many people are incapable of abandoning beliefs acquired in childhood notwithstanding overwhelming logical evidence that those beliefs are likely to be unfounded.

The phenomenon is compounded, in my view, by the methods that are used to teach relativity, which are largely showing how equations can be derived, rather than teaching the student to get a self-consistent conceptual model of what is actually happening. That explains why there are so many questions on this forum and elsewhere that show that the people asking them, and many of those providing misleading replies, have not managed to grasp the concepts. Understandably, from that perspective, people will question whether the theory really can be true.

Comment: Right, after all there are still people believing the earth is flat.

Comment: I, too, was "naturally gifted at physics at school" (I got myself into the Chinese National Olympiad Team in my high school days), and too, "found relativity extremely difficult to internalise". I do not blame Euclidean geometry I have learned because I think there is truth in it. On the opposite, I started to suspect Relativity five months ago. So now I am one of those people.

Comment: @ anna v @JMac Are there any reputable physicists/mathematicians such as Ehrenfest, Mocanu, Lewis, and Tolman (for right-angle lever paradox) among those flat earth advocates?! I mean that relativity theory, contrary to the flat earth model, was/is very challenging for many professional scientists. Even Einstein himself, upon noticing a version of the twin paradox, found it "peculiar". Does this mean that there was a dark (obscure) side of relativity for Einstein himself?

Answer (score -3):

Special Relativity makes perfect sense mathematically but little sense as a description of reality. That's at least my mental stimulus to not accept the theory.

> ... or there is a weird deficiency about special relativity that has not just been revealed so far?!

An honest answer to this question might result in this thread getting locked. 
Having said that, you might find the following link interesting, if you are really looking for a possible answer to your questions: [link to a Quora answer](https://www.quora.com/What-if-Einsteins-theory-of-relativity-is-proved-wrong/answer/Georgi-Stanimirov).